# Laravel returning 404 on newly created routes

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to work with some ajax inside of laravel, still quite new to all of it, but I've noticed that for some reason everytime I create a new route I get a 404 regardless of what it is that I'm doing.  For example, something as simple as:

```
Route::get('templateswitch', function() {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Will still return out a 404, it is listed in the routes, and I've tried running the optimization through artisan too, so far no dice.

I'm not sure if it's just something I'm doing wrong in the code or something wrong with my server.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Full web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\SwitchController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TemplateSwitch_Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('templateswitch', function() {
    return 'Hello World';
});
Route::post('/switch', [TemplateSwitch_Controller::class, 'ajaxGetByID'])->name('test_templateswitch');
Route::get('/', [TemplateSwitch_Controller::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: You have done ```php artisan route:clear``` ?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the cache too.

Comment: Is this in `web.php` or `api.php`?

Comment: It is within web.php

Comment: Perhaps your routes are conflicting, please update your question with the full contents of ```web.php```

Comment: Do you have some kind of wildcard route, like `Route::get('/{something}', ...);`? Depending on where that is placed in your `routes/web.php`, it can override other routes, since `/templateswitch` technically matches `/{something}`. This happens a lot if you have something like `/{id}`, and that Route uses `Model::findOrFail($id)` (automatic 404 if `$id` isn't found).

Comment: I've added the full contents of the web.php file, I don't have wild cards persay, just the very basic routes it comes with, with the two additions that I made.

Comment: are you using a webserver or `php artisan serve`?

Comment: I'm using my webserver, but it's a basic webserver with cPanel, nothing crazy in the config, just a standard LAMP stack.

Comment: Are you seeing the Laravel 404 page or the default Apache 404 page ?

Comment: can you run `php artisan route:list` and check it does exist?